# Import all wallet addresses efficiently for explorer

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I'm trying to build an explorer and I need to pull information about the wallet address such as transactions.

Do I have to loop through everything with importaddress or is there an easier way?

I already have the blockchain indexed so I can look at transactions outside my own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import multiple things at the same time using the Bitcoin Core RPC, then [`importmulti`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/importmulti/) is the best way to do so. It takes an array of JSON objects which can contain descriptors, scriptPubKeys, addresses, keys, and other metadata. It is a very useful RPC.

Comment: would i have to do this every single address? how would the loop for php look like? would i have to loop through every block then every transaction?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm not sure I understand your question. You can pass all the addresses into a single call to `importmulti` and it will import all of them at once.

Comment: im trying to build an explorer, but i need to add every since wallet on a watch list. do i have to loop through the block hashes then loop through the transactions? i have to essentially add every since address to this function?

Comment: @Daniel if you want to add *every* address ever used on the blockchain, then you might want to reconsider your approach. Bitcoin Core is not designed as a blockchain explorer backend. In that case, you should create your own database and store all the data yourself rather than importing every single address into a wallet.

Comment: how can i obtain information about that address other than adding the watchlist wallets?

Comment: Manually parse the blockchain for all transaction data using your own program, Bitcoin Core is not designed for that purpose so using it would be inefficient.

Comment: If we maintain a separate table for all the balances, how to we deal with block re-orgs?